# Android StopWatch - How to resume my time

Tags: android, timer, resume, stopwatch

I'm making stopwatch application for Android. I want when stop is clicked the time to stop, and when the Start is clicked again the time to be resumed. I'm using http://www.goldb.org/stopwatchjava.html class. Currently the time is resumed on click on Start button, but when i click Stop after second time it's showing bad time. Again on Start button the time is resumed correctly. Here's my code:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_START_TIMER:
            timer.start(); //start timer
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE_TIMER);
            break;

        case MSG_UPDATE_TIMER:

            time = timer.getElapsedTime() + timeStoped;

            hh = time / 3600000;
            hours.setText("" + formatter.format(hh));
            time = time - hh * 3600000;

            mm = time / 60000;
            minutes.setText("" + formatter.format(mm));
            time = time - mm * 60000;

            ss = time / 1000;
            seconds.setText("" + formatter.format(ss));
            time = time - ss * 1000;

            millis.setText("" + formatter.format(time / 10));

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_TIMER,REFRESH_RATE); //text view is updated every second, 
            break;      
                                                                             //though the timer is still running
        case MSG_STOP_TIMER:

            mHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIMER); // no more updates.
            timer.stop();//stop timer

            time = timer.getElapsedTime();
            timeStoped = timeStoped + time;

            hh = time / 3600000;
            hours.setText("" + formatter.format(hh));
            time = time - hh * 3600000;

            mm = time / 60000;
            minutes.setText("" + formatter.format(mm));
            time = time - mm * 60000;

            ss = time / 1000;
            seconds.setText("" + formatter.format(ss));
            time = time - ss * 1000;

            millis.setText("" + formatter.format(time / 10));

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

the Listener for the button Start/Stop :

```
startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!startIsPressed) {
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_START_TIMER);
                startIsPressed = true;
                startBtn.setText(R.string.stop);
            } else {
                startIsPressed = false;
                startBtn.setText(R.string.start);
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_STOP_TIMER);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you have add Stopwatch  class from http://www.goldb.org/stopwatchjava.html in your project?

Comment: yes, i have added. The problem is that  timer.start(); is called every time when start is pressed (so on Stop the bad time is shown), but I don't have clue how to solve it

Comment: can you explain more about your problem.bez i'm not getting you?

Comment: Scenario: 
1. Click Start button start counting
2. Click Stop button we have 00:00:05.35
3. Click again on Start it continues from 00:00:05.35
4. Click Stop shows bad time (time measured from 3. to 4.)
5. Click Start it is resuming correctly

On every Stop (except for the first one) bad time is shown

Comment: you have try after replacing timeStoped = timeStoped + time;

            hh = time / 3600000;
            hours.setText("" + formatter.format(hh));
            time = time - hh * 3600000;

            mm = time / 60000;
            minutes.setText("" + formatter.format(mm));
            time = time - mm * 60000;

            ss = time / 1000;
            seconds.setText("" + formatter.format(ss));
            time = time - ss * 1000;
with millis.setText("" + timer.getElapsedTime());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to replace:

```
    time = timer.getElapsedTime();
    timeStoped = timeStoped + time;
```

with:

```
    time = timer.getElapsedTime() + timeStopped;
    timeStopped = time;
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to set the time in hour:minute:second format might be:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm ss SSS");
String[] parsedTime = formatter.format(time).split(" ");
hours.setText(parsedTime[0]);
minutes.setText(parsedTime[1]);
seconds.setText(parsedTime[2]);
millis.setText(parsedTime[3]);
```

To keep accurate time after multiple stop your need to change this:

```
        time = timer.getElapsedTime();
        timeStoped = timeStoped + time;
```

To something that checks for a previous elapsed `time` as well, maybe like this:

```
        time = timer.getElapsedTime() + time;
        timeStoped = timeStoped + time;
```

And these are the same as:

```
        time += timer.getElapsedTime();
        timeStoped += time;
```